# How to use array_merge_recursive with an incremental variable?

Tags: php

I created my array within a foreach loop like so ..

```
$final_orders[]= array($cake_type_size => array('size' => $cake_size , 'type'=>$cake_type[0]->name, 'qty' =>  $order_item['qty'] ));
```

Outside of that foreach loop I would like to use `array_merge_recursive` so all the keys that are the same will be merged together

This works ..

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($final_orders[1],$final_orders[2],$final_orders[3]));
```

But I have n type of `$final_orders` I need some way to constantly increment and merge to lump the same keys together.

Comment: And if you use merge in first loop after every iteration and merge only 2 arrays?

Comment: @Unlink the issue with doing a simple array_merge is that if the key '$cake_type_size' is the same I need it to lump everything together rather than dropping the duplicate

Comment: I think something like that

$results = array();
foreach ...
$results = array_merge_recursive($results, array($cake_type_size => array('size' => $cake_size , 'type'=>$cake_type[0]->name, 'qty' =>  $order_item['qty'])));